# how to truncate first few characters char array c++

Tags: c++, char, strncpy

I have a `char array` called `names[50]`

Basically, I use

```
strncpy(this->names, names, sizeof(names))
```

however this will only truncate characters at the end.

How do I truncate characters from the start?

For example, `BillSteveLinusMikeGeorgeBillSteveLinusMikeGeorgeGeorge` should be `teveLinusMikeGeorgeBillSteveLinusMikeGeorgeGeorge`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I think they are looking to get substrings from the left end or the right end. If you are familiar with Python, like slicing `[:5]` or `[-5:]` for example

Comment: use `std::copy(names+i, names+j, names.begin())`

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly then using the string you showed as an example  you have to write

```
strncpy( this->names, names + 5, sizeof(names) - 5 );
```

Comment: But what happens if the name is `60`, then it has to delete first `10` characters. Number of characters can be different everytime, say it is `70` it has to remove `20` from the start

Comment: @Rews Prog You have to specify required number of characters you want to skip from the beginning..

Answer (score 0):

You can change the source address for strncpy:

```
strncpy(this->names, &(names[10]), num_of_chars_to_copy);
```

Notice that no null-character is implicitly appended at the end of the destination string if the source string is longer than num.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be clear what you want to do... is names[] variable in length from call to call? Is this->names a fixed length? Note that the length for the number of bytes to copy should be the number of bytes available  in this->names... Otherwise you run the risk of overflowing the memory.

Answer (score 0):

I designed for you this simple function, You can use it as reference code for more complex issue:

```
void BackStrCopy(char* src, char* dest, int srcsize, int destsize)
{
    if(srcsize >= destsize )
    {
        do
            dest[destsize--] = src[srcsize--];
        while( destsize + 1 );
    }
}

int main()
{
  char* src    = "BillSteveLinusMikeGeorgeBillSteveLinusMikeGeorgeGeorge";
  char  dest[50];
  BackStrCopy(src, dest, strlen(src), 25);
}
```

I tested it end work.

I thing that the function code does not require any comment:)
If my solution help you, please remember to check it as answered.

Ciao